# old nested functions

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

Find all functions $g$ that map the positive integers to the positive integers such that $g^5(y)=2022y$.

I have tried common functions such as the reciprocal and the fifth root but these do not give positive integer values. Am I missing something like a special function or construction?

Note that the appearance of the number $2022$ means the question is from last year; it is most likely not from an ongoing contest, if it resembles a contest problem at all.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $g$ is such a function. Note that since $g^5$ is injective, so is $g$.
On the other hand, since $g^5$ is not surjective, neither is $g$. In fact, if $n$ is not divisible by $2022^m$, $g^{-5m}(n)$ does not exist. Take any enumeration $r_1, r_2, \ldots$ of the natural numbers not divisible by $2022$.  We define $g(r_i) = r_{i+1}$
for $i \equiv 1,2,3,4 \mod 5$, but if $i \equiv 0 \mod 5$ we take $g(r_i) = 2022 r_{i-4}$; more generally $g(2022^m r_i) = 2022^m r_{i+1}$ if $i \equiv 1,2,3,4 \mod 5$,
and $g(2022^m r_i) = 2022^{m+1} r_{i-4}$ if $i \equiv 0 \mod 5$.